# Control screen brightness on Windows 10 with Python3.X

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I want to write a script in Python (3.5 here) to control the brightness of the screen on my laptop (got a HP EliteBook, don't know if it's important). Does anyone know if there's some code/module for this ?

Thanks in advance everyone, have a good day !

Comment: [PyWin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found a way to interact with the screen in Windows 10. Thanks martineau, PyWin32 was a part of the solution. WMI package was the other part.

```
wmi.WMI(namespace='wmi').WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods()[0].WmiSetBrightness(brightness, 0)
```

where brightness is an int between 0 and 100.

Comment: But does it works with a desktop?

Comment: @ThunderHorn No reason to.