# How to use python/pygame to turn off certain pixels on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, pygame, pixel

I have an old Windows 7 laptop that I want to turn into a simple clock. I used pygame to fill the screen with (0,0,0) black pixels, and then drew the time in light blue pixels over that.

[image: The clock when all lights are off in the room]

The problem is, (0,0,0) black pixels aren’t the same as turned off pixels. As you can see in the picture, even with the brightness of the laptop as low as possible, the black pixels still have a brightness to them. This makes the clock act as a night light, which is not what I want.

I want those black pixels completely gone - like when the laptop is turned off and no brightness is coming from the screen - while keeping the blue pixels on. Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

If it is possible, I would guess the solution is either to change something in Windows 7 settings or do something I didn’t think of with pygame or another python library.

—Research Thus Far—

The top reply to this post claims it is impossible to “turn off” pixels on the computer side: https://superuser.com/questions/1155129/how-to-turn-off-make-black-certain-pixels-on-a-screen

Interesting suggestions such as changing the contrast settings in Windows or downloading a dimmer program, although the OP said neither idea made it dark enough: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-dim-the-screen-brightness-further-than/ad7388af-e07a-4d9b-b71d-0e3f77a61c1c

Backlighting info: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/3hm6pd/eli5_why_dont_pixels_that_show_the_color_black/

Comment: You should inform yourself how displays work and what the job of the backlight is. Then you will see that there is nothing like a pixel that is *off* as you named it.

Comment: @KlausD. Unless he has an OLED monitor for the display, but that is unlikely, and wouldn't be something that you would need to specially toggle through pygame.

Comment: Ok, so assuming it’s an LED display, is there a way to have python turn off the backlight without actually stopping the code in the background? (I could have the clock turn off at night and turn back on during the day)

Comment: Promising: https://github.com/pl31/python-liquidcrystal_i2c/issues/1

Comment: That project you linked to seems to be for a particular LCD panel, not for monitors in general. Since you are on windows, I would look into programmatically controlling the brightness of the monitor using the Windows API, using a library like PyWin32. I haven't used that library, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599375/control-screen-brightness-on-windows-10-with-python3-x) shows that it should be at least possible to do. Of course, that would just change the brightness  of the entire monitor, not just the "black pixels."

Comment: @CodeSurgeon thanks

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/arjun024/turn-off-screen Although it doesn't say how to turn the screen back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While specific pixels cannot be turned on or off for an LED display, the light behind the display (backlight) can be controlled.

This means the clock can be on during the day and entirely turned off at night - although it, unfortunately, can never be partially on like the question was hoping for.

Python code to turn the backlight on and off (sleep is also an option for windows):

```
def backlight(argument):
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'): # expecting "on" or "off" as the argument
        import os
        os.system("xset dpms force " + argument)

    elif sys.platform.startswith('win'): # expecting "on", "off", or "sleep" as the argument
        import win32gui
        import win32con

        if argument == "on":
          win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND,
                               win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)
        if argument == "off":
          win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND,
                               win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)
        if argument == "sleep":
          win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND,
                               win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 1)
```

Comment: Good job! If you need more fine-grained control of the backlight in linux at least, you can take a look at xrandr.